# Jquery Datatables Error: Invalid JSON primitive: draw

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatable

I am trying to implement server side processing with JQuery Datatables 1.10.5. Here is my code for the DataTable

```
$('#userTable').dataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'statusFilter': $('#status-filter').val(),
                'secondaryFilterOption': $('#secondary-filter-option').val(),
                'secondaryFilterOperator': $('#secondary-filter-operator').val(),
                'secondaryFilterText': $('#secondary-filter-text').val()
            },

            url: "UserManagement.aspx/GetUsers",

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("success");
                    },
           error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(jqXhr.responseText);

                    }
        },
        scrollY: "500px",
        scrollCollapse: true,
        columnDefs: [
        {
            "targets": [0],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        },
        {
            "targets": [8],
            "visible": true,
            "searchable": false,
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<img title="Edit" class="action-button edit-user center" src="/ntims/images/icon_edit.gif" id="' + row.id + '" />';
            },
        }],
        columns: [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "lastName" },
            { "data": "firstName" },
            { "data": "login" },
            { "data": "command" },
            { "data": "email" },
            { "data": "phone" },
            { "data": "status" }

        ]
    });
```

I get the following error during the ajax call:

```
{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: draw.","StackTrace":" at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}
```

"draw" is something that datatables sends to the server. I have no control over this variable to my knowleged. I have looked at the Jquery Forums and did some other research but I cannot firgure out this issue. I have seen people have issues about other parameters that THEY are sending, but "draw" is something Jquery sends, not me.

Answer (score 0):

You can give "bServerSide" : true for serverSide: true.
If it doesnt work check with "serverSide": true