# Datatables issue with invalid JSON primitive draw

Tags: c#, json, ajax, datatables

I have seen this question: [Jquery Datatables Error: Invalid JSON primitive: draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514788/jquery-datatables-error-invalid-json-primitive-draw)

It could not help me solve the issue.

I am using Datatables, I get an error for the AJAX call. Here is the JS code:

```
function loadparttrackings() {
    // Call the datatable on the overview div and link back to server side
    $('#overviewFilteredPartTrackings').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "filter": true,
        "orderMulti": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": window.applicationPath + "/Launches/GetFilteredPartTrackingRecords",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": function (d) {
                d.partNumber = $('#FilterPartNumber').val();
                d.segment = $('#FilterSegment').val();
                d.commodity = $('#FilterCommodity').val();
            }
        },
        // This is needed to hide the ID field and make it not searchable
        "columnDefs":
        [{
                "targets": [1],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
        }],
        "columns": [

            {
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="#" onclick=EditRecord("' + row.ID + '"); >Edit</a>'; }
            },
            // more columns omitted
    });
}
```

The issue came up when I added the `"type": "POST",` to the AJAX part of the function. Now I get the error `invalid json primitive draw`.

Here is the code for the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetFilteredPartTrackingRecords(DataTableAjaxPostModel model, string partNumber, string commodity, string segment)
    {
        // Getting the data and such


        return Json(new
        {
            // this is what datatables wants sending back
            draw = model.draw,
            recordsTotal = 1000, // TODO CHANGE
            recordsFiltered = 1000, // TODO CHANGE
            data = result
        });   
    }
```

And here is the code for the model that I use:

```
public class DataTableAjaxPostModel
{
    // properties are not capital due to json mapping
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public List<Column> columns { get; set; }
    public Search search { get; set; }
    public List<Order> order { get; set; }
}



public class Column
{
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool searchable { get; set; }
    public bool orderable { get; set; }
    public Search search { get; set; }
}



public class Search
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string regex { get; set; }
}



public class Order
{
    public int column { get; set; }
    public string dir { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"data":JSON.stringify({

            partNumber: $('#FilterPartNumber').val();
            segment: $('#FilterSegment').val();
            commodity: $('#FilterCommodity').val();
   })
```

And add the `contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"` in ajax options.

Comment: Hello, this did not fix it for me. I fixed it in an other way though,, I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing the following:

remove the type: post from the ajax call.

```
"ajax": {
            "url": window.applicationPath + "/Launches/GetFilteredPartTrackingRecords",
            "data": function (d) {
                d.partNumber = $('#FilterPartNumber').val();
                d.segment = $('#FilterSegment').val();
                d.commodity = $('#FilterCommodity').val();
            }
        },
```

Change the controller method to get

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetFilteredPartTrackingRecords(DataTableAjaxPostModel model, string partNumber, string commodity, string segment)
```

Change the JSON request behavior so I can return through GET

```
return Json(new
        {
            // this is what datatables wants sending back
            draw = model.draw,
            recordsTotal = 1000, // TODO CHANGE
            recordsFiltered = 1000, // TODO CHANGE
            data = result
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I do not know if this is the best/ a good solution but this works for me.